# How to create a new dictionary from another one by modifying specific values (join the values of two keys into one)

Tags: python

I have reviewed many questions on stackoverflow where what is done is to iterate a dictionary through a for loop and change the value for a specific key.

Like this:

```
for key, value in inputdict.items():
    inputdict[key] = newvalue
```

Or just using `update`.

I have not found an answer for this specific case and the truth is that I do not know very well how to proceed.

Let's say I have the following dictionary:

```
dict1 = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": "1964"
}
```

And let's say I want a new dictionary (copying the previous dictionary but modifying the value of a certain key):

```
dict2 = {
  "brand": "Ford 1964",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": "1964"
}
```

Basically I want the same as dict1, but I want to 'merge' the values of the keys `brand` and `model` into the brand key.

`(dict1) Ford -> (dict2) Ford 1964`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I did:

```
    dict2 = {}

    for key, value in dict1.items():
        if key == 'brand':
            for key2, value2 in dict1.items():
                if key2 == 'year':
                    dict2[key] = str(value) + " " + str(value2)
        else:
            dict2[key] = value
```

It works but I don't know if it's the most optimal solution (I don't like nesting for loops...but it's the only way I can think of to make it work)

Is there any other way to get the same result in python without importing libraries?

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This perhaps?

```
dict2 = dict1.copy()
dict2['brand'] = ' '.join([dict2["brand"], dict2["year"]])
```

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately :( Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you explain what did not work? The result should be exactly as you described.

Comment: In fact I can't use copy(), due to project requirements I can't use more imports

Comment: I added a solution that worked for me, but I think it can be improved.

Comment: `copy()` is a built-in method of dictionaries, it does not require any imports.

Comment: Sorry, I should have cleared it up from the beginning. The dictionaries used in my project are not 'standard'. That is why I get the following error: 'CaseInsensitiveDict' object has no attribute 'copy'.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
def dict_update(dict1):
    dict2 = {}
    for key in dict1:
        if key == 'brand':
            dict2[key] = str(dict_['brand'])+' '+str(dict_['year'])
        elif key not in dict2:
            dict2[key] = str(dict_[key])
    return dict2
```